# How can an app have different name on AppStore and iPhone home screen?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6, app-store-connect

I have noticed an app whose Appstore name is different than the one installed on any iDevice. Please have a look at the screenshots.

[image: This is the screenshot from iTunes. The name of the app here is TrendingApp]

[image: This screenshot is from iPhone home-screen. The name of the app here is Trending]

How can I get this functionality for any app which I intend to upload?

Answer (score 2):

The App name that appears in the app store is entered when you submit your app or when you update the binary.

The launcher name that appears below the icon in iOS, is configured in your project configuration - click on your Target, go to Build Settings, then to the Packaging section and change the value for 'Product Name'

[image]

I should not that this build setting sets the $(PRODUCT_NAME) variable used to define the Bundle Name and Bundle Display Name

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apps can have different names on AppStore and on physical devices. But developers shouldn't do this as per Apple's guidelines. There is a danger of the app being rejected. 
See 3.4 in the below screenshot from Apple's App Store Review Guidelines.
So I cannot get this functionality even if it is possible and this replies my basic question.

[image]